# Bootstrap nav walker custom split menu, custom mobile view menu php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to Bootstrap and php.
I want my navigation to have a centered brand with logo and the links to different pages left and right next to the logo. Then I want to have social media icons on the top right. 
In the mobile view I want a different order of menu items. the brand with logo on the top and the social media at the bottom.
Does this make any sense? Here is my code so far. I have no idea how I can use the navwalker on this custom menu.

```
            <a class = "navbar-brand visible-xs" href = "<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo">"  width="50"> 
            </a><!-- /navbar-brand visible-xs -->

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button> <!-- /navbar-toggle -->

        </div> <!-- /navbar-header -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right  hidden-xs social ">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-500px"></i></a></li>
            </ul><!-- /hidden-xs social -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown hidden-xs"><a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img id="logo-navbar-middle" src="C:\Users\Carolin_2\Desktop\nicole\logonew.png" width="50"</img></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">LEISTUNGEN</a></li>
                <li><a href="">KONTAKT</a></li> 
            </ul><!-- /navbar-nav -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center visible-xs  social nav-pills">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-500px"></i></a></li>

            </ul><!-- /visible-xs social --> 

        </div> <!-- /navbar-collapse-->

    </div><!-- /container fluid-->
```

CSS Code

```
/* === NAVBAR ===*/


.navbar{
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: 0;


}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
    vertical-align: top;


}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle -.icon-bar{

    color: white;


}
```

Can anybody help me or give me some advice?

Best,

Carolina

Comment: Can you show your CSS code?

Comment: I will post the code up in the question.

Comment: @CarolinePdw Can you create you working script here -> http://jsfiddle.net so that, I can see the output and help you?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Sorry that i couldn't answer earlier. I don't know if I did it right. It certainly does not look right in the preview.
https://jsfiddle.net/rqdey3wm/

Comment: it's working fine in bootstrap.. here are two screenshots of what it looks like. 
http://rookiephotography.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/screenshot1.jpg
http://rookiephotography.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/screenshot2.jpg

Comment: @CarolinePdw I'm sorry. But you jsfiddle looks different from your screenshot. So I cannot help you to solve this issue. Do you have any other way to show me this same page with html & css working? So that I could help you? Thanks